# Def vs. val, functional syntax not working in Scala.js?

Tags: scala, scala.js

To give you a minimal example:

```
object Main extends JSApp
{
   val someThing: String = determineSomething("test")   

   def main(): Unit =
   {
       println(someThing)
   }
}
```

Now, two possibilities here:

```
private def determineSomething(s: String): String = "succeeded"
```

If the project is executed like this, well, I get a log entry saying

> succeeded

But when I use the more functional syntax:

```
private val determineSomething: (s: String) => "succeeded"
```

I get

```
TypeError: this.determineSomething$1 is null
```

I am curious as to the why this happens as in the (JVM) repl, both ways work perfectly fine.

Comment: Where does the definition of `determineSomething` appear? If it appears _after_ the definition of `something`, then maybe it's because `determineSomething` will not have been initialized at that point. Can you include the full code for that version of your code?

Comment: @MikeAllen Make this an answer and I will accept. I was not aware of this, just hoping into functional scala. It make sense, of course, but I was under the impression that the compiler would know if it's a FunctionX it must be available "globally"

Comment: @Sorona when you use `val`, the right hand side of the expression is eagerly (immediately) evaluated. If it does not exist at that time, you cannot call it. In the REPL you probably defined the function first, as it would not make sense otherwise, while in the actual code you may have gone the opposite way, which is fine for a lazily evaluated `def`, but not so for a `val` :)

Comment: @Sorona I'd say the opposite: in functional programming you should expect functions to behave just like any other values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is something like this:

```
object Main extends JSApp {
  private val determineSomething: String => String = (s: String) => "succeeded"

  val someThing: String = determineSomething("test")   

  def main(): Unit = {
    println(someThing)
  }
}
```

The declaration of `determineSomething` needs to come before the declaration of `something`, otherwise the former will be uninitialized when the compiler attempts to initialize the latter.